# Using a recursive method to find the smallest element in a subtree given the root: what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

So I have a homework question where I'm supposed to use a recursive method to "find the minimum element within a subtree rooted at the specified node"

And then I'm given this as my starting point:

```
   public TreeNode
{
    int data;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
}
```

and

```
/**
Finds the minimum value for the subtree that is 
rooted at a given node
@param n The root of the subtree
@return The minimum value 
PRECONDITION: n is not null.
*/
int min(TreeNode n)
{
  // COMPLETE THE BODY OF THIS METHOD
}
```

Now, I've got a very basic driver program written to insert nodes into the tree and I've written my recursive method, but it seems to be counting up instead of down, here's my method:

```
int min(TreeNode n){      
if(n.left != null) {
  n = n.left;
  min(n);
  System.out.println("N is now " + n.value);
 }
    return n.value;
   }
```

**Output of my code:**

```
Building tree with rootvalue 25
  =================================
  Inserted 11 to left of node 25
  Inserted 15 to right of node 11
  Inserted 16 to right of node 15
  Inserted 23 to right of node 16
  Inserted 79 to right of node 25
  Inserted 5 to left of node 11
  Inserted 4 to left of node 5
  Inserted 2 to left of node 4
    Root is 25
    N is now 2
    N is now 4
    N is now 5
    N is now 11
    The minimum integer in the given nodes subtree is: 11
```

Can someone please explain to me why this doesn't work?

Comment: Please add the [homework] tag to homework questions.

Comment: You don't check for the minimum value anywhere. You just call your min method recursively, voiding its result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** this is all assuming you're in a Binary Search Tree, so returning the minimum element means returning the left-most element.

This means your recursive call is quite simple:

```
min(node):
  if this node has a left node:
    return min(node.left)
  if this node does not have a left node:
    return this node's value
```

The logic is that if we don't have another left node then we are the left-most node, so we are the minimum value.

Now, in Java:

```
int min(TreeNode n){
  if (n.left == null)
    return n.value;
  return min(n.left); // n.left cannot be null here
}
```

Now to explain your results, consider how this method works. It calls the method on the next node (`min(n.left)`) before continuing. In your case you had a `println` after this recursive call. Therefore the `println` *inside* the recursive call went first. So your prints started at the bottom of the tree and worked their way back up. This explains the "reverse order" printing.
Your method then returned `11` as your result because (as another answer has explained) your `n = n.left` didn't affect any of your recursive sub-calls, only the one in the current function call. This means you returned the left node of the root, rather than the furthest left child.

I hope this makes sense. If you need clarification on anything leave a comment or something. Recursion can be quite tricky to get your head around at first.

Comment: ahh yes, your answer does indeed make sense. Thank you very much for the reply. You're right, recursion is still a little confusing for me, so I'm sure that I will have to come back and look at your answer some more. Thank you again!

Comment: @mange shouldn't the third line of your pseudocode say `return min(node.left)` instead?

Comment: Wow. Thanks @user224567893! You're completely right, and I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Java is call-by-value, *not* by reference -- although references are passed by value. But what that really means in this case is that the call to `min(n)` does *not* change what the variable `n` refers to -- it doesn't do anything at all.  What you should probably be doing is `return min(n)`.

Comment: There is no statement about the binary tree being sorted, so returning min(n) is not sufficient. There is no comparison anywhere.

Comment: @TheBlastOne: if you construct the tree in his example it's strong evidence that the tree is sorted. I think we can assume it's a Binary Search Tree.

Comment: Agree. Thought homework questions are often pitfall questions by intent in this regard, so...nevermind.

Comment: @prajeesh -- which code??? There is just a print log for the insert operation. Sure this is a hint, but there is no source code shown for the insertion. As I said, this could have been part of the "pun" of the homework question. Sorry for being too precise, but no reason to label that precision incorrect.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I meant output he gave

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, InitializationError {
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new SimpleLayout(), "System.out"));
    Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ALL);

    TreeNode n1 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode n2 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode n3 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode n4 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode n5 = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode n6 = new TreeNode();
    n1.data = 110;
    n1.left = n2;
    n1.right = n3;
    n2.data = 15;
    n2.left = n4;
    n2.right = null;
    n3.data = 3;
    n3.left = null;
    n3.right = null;
    n4.data = 4;
    n4.left = null;
    n4.right = n5;
    n5.data = 12;
    n5.left = n6;
    n5.right = null;
    n6.data = 19;
    n6.left = null;
    n6.right = null;

    System.out.print("min=" + min(n1));
}

static public class TreeNode {
    int data;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
}

static int min(TreeNode n) {
    return min(n, n.data);
}

static int min(TreeNode n, int min) {
    System.out.println("N is now " + n.data);
    int currentMin = min;
    if (n.left != null && n.right != null) {
        final int left = min(n.left);
        final int right = min(n.right);

        if (left < right) {
            currentMin = left;
        } else {
            currentMin = right;
        }
    } else if (n.left != null) {
        currentMin = min(n.left);
    } else if (n.right != null) {
        currentMin = min(n.right);
    }
    if (currentMin < min) {
        return currentMin;
    } else {
        return min;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT is:

```
N is now 110
N is now 15
N is now 4
N is now 12
N is now 19
N is now 3
min=3
```

You need to use some [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) algoritm, for checking every node of the tree. Also you need to store current finded minimum. Pass this minimum into recursive function. It is calling "accumulator".

Comment: Why are you using an accumulator? Usually you'd use an accumulator if you needed to accumulate something, but this just gets passed straight up.

Comment: @mange Of course, you right. I just want to show this technique. It may be useful for him(Kyle).

Comment: Fair enough. I might suggest that in this case it may have been unhelpful (given the lack of understanding about recursion generally), but I can't contest the utility of accumulators in many circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The last statement in your method implementation returns the node n's value. As n starts with the root and is replaced by its left child (if exists) you always get the value of the root's left child.

The following code should do it:

```
int min(final Tree n){
    int result;
    if(n == null){
        result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else {
        result = n.value;
        final int leftResult = min(n.left);
        if(leftResult < result){
          result = leftResult;
        }
        final int rightResult = min(n.right);
        if(rightResult < result){
          result = rightResult;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or you could use the Visitor pattern (you would need to make your tree Iterable then and pass the values to the Visitor one-by-one):

```
interface TreeVisitor {
    void accept(int value);
}

class MinTreeVisistor implements TreeVisitor {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    @Override
    public void accept(int value) {
        if(value < this.min) {
          this.min = value;
        }
    }
}
```